# Automatically remove datapoints to change dataset distribution

Tags: python

I have a dataset generator for machine learning purposes which unfortunately is producing a distribution as shown in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liXfu.jpg). Note that I can't really change the data generation process very much.

This dataset is heavily skewed towards the centre. I would like to be able to fit this dataset to a more uniform distribution by removing some of those central datapoints. I am a beginner to programming and data science so I am unaware of any methods in which I can do this.

If anyone can point to a library or function I can utilise to achieve this it would be much appreciated. I am using python3 and my data is stored in a csv.

Thanks!

Comment: are generated data points 1-dimensional (i.e., a single number)?

Comment: @Marat the generated datapoints are 17 columns wide. I want to fit the dataset by the number of steering angle instances which is one column of the each datapoint. I hope that answers the question.

Comment: I see. I would estimate PDF of the target variable then, and drop sample with probability proportional to PDF at the point

Comment: Alright, thanks @Marat, I will look into it!